# Xamarin cycle 7 IOS IPA output now in a datetime folder

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have just updated to the latest version of Xamarin studio, however when I try to build my solution using XBuild, through our continuous integration server it now generates the IPA file in a data time folder, (within the usual bin\iphone\Ad-hoc folders) e.g. :

```
Finisher3 2016-06-09 11-57-45\Finisher3.ipa
```

however I do not understand why it now does this - in the previous version it gave me a file as follows:

```
Finisher3-1.68.1.1.ipa
```

Does anyone know how to get it back to setting the version number again, rather than putting it in a date time folder which makes it fairly impractical to copy the IPA to a release folder once I have finished building it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**
Old solution doesn't work for latest Xamarin release and is not suggested.
**Official information and suggestions on solving the problem are published here:**

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/#New_MSBuild_property_IpaPackageDir_to_customize_.ipa_output_location

However, in my case, having several build machines with ~30 builds editing build definitions or .csproj files on all of them is a nightmare, especially on Friday.

Here is a workaround that I am using for the moment.
Between line 1655/1656 insert this code

`<IpaPackageDir Condition="'$(IpaPackageDir)' == ''">$(DeviceSpecificOutputPath)</IpaPackageDir>`

Then insert following line after 1661:

`<IpaPackageName Condition="'$(IpaPackageName)' == '' And '$(_BundleVersion)' != ''">$(_AppBundleName)-$(_BundleVersion).ipa</IpaPackageName>`

After your changes this is how file will look. Lines 1656 and 1662 are new.
[image: fixed targets file for Xamarin ipa location problem]

Good luck, have fun!

---

*Outdated solution:*

According to the support@xamarin.com, editing `Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets` for **now** is the suggested workaround (Option 2 from Johan's answer).

Since the accepted answer only shows reason of the problem (Option 2), here is how to workaround the issue.

The workaround (on Mac) is to go to the folder `/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1/` and open file `Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets`

(or open file directly `/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/2.1/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets`).

If you are on Windows, then the file you need to edit is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets`

Then change line 1607 to

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <IpaPackageName Condition="'$(IpaPackageName)' != '' And !$(IpaPackageName.EndsWith ('.ipa', StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))">$(IpaPackageName).ipa</IpaPackageName>
        <IpaPackageName Condition="'$(IpaPackageName)' == '' And '$(_BundleVersion)' != ''">$(_AppBundleName)-$(_BundleVersion).ipa</IpaPackageName>
        <IpaPackageName Condition="'$(IpaPackageName)' == ''">$(_AppBundleName).ipa</IpaPackageName>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

and line 1734 to

```
OutputFile="$(OutputPath)$(IpaPackageName)"
```

These changes are taken from the `Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets` of previous stable release (5.10.3).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's the one proposed by Xamarin support. Also, the first one can fail in some build system tasks (such as Bamboo). As I found out the hard way. :(

Comment: Cheers, I had success with the first answer a while ago, but had to come back to my own question today as I had managed to update to the next version of Xamarin - which of course overwrites the changes once again... oh the fun!

Comment: Good point, Chris. Let me ask support if they fixed the problem in this update or not.

Comment: So far the updates in Stable channel do not include fix and if you install it you have to do it over again

Comment: I'm just wondering how long could it take to learn that 1767 lines file with targets? :) Thanks @AlexSorokoletov

Comment: What is the the part "1.68.1.1"? Is it version number or build number? Mine is always 1.0, but my app version is 1.7 and build version is 1.0.

Comment: 1.68.1.1 is a build version. Probably Chris uses a different versioning approach than you.